# Frequency Array formula EXCEL not calculating

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I am having problems with the Frequency function in excel. This example is from the CTR SHIFT ENTER book and in it is an example, data below. In cell E5 to E10 the solution gives an array formula - `{=FREQUENCY(A5:A17,C5:C9)}`which calculates the results see below

DATA

```
(sec)       Upper Limits
65.52       40.00
52.10       45.00
46.50       50.00
39.40       55.00
43.50       60.00
46.80       
47.80       
48.10       
48.00       .
43.50       
52.30       
56.35       
41.85
```

RESULTS already on sheet

```
Frequency
1
3
5
2
1
1
```

My problem is I am copying the formula EXACTLY as above and pressing CSE into the cells H5:H10 but my results are all coming back as 1 which seems to be only counting the lowest limit in my bin_array. I have checked and the formulas match all the way down.

Comment: Sounds like you've entered that formula into each of the cells within the range H5:H10 separately, and pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER for each, rather than first selecting the entire range H5:H10, then entering that formula in the formula bar and only once pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: thanks XOR LX thats worked, I though it was something simple

Answer (score 1):

It seems that FREQUENCY doesn't like row inputs (at least, non-adjacent input rows), you get the same result.  Worked OK once I used (adjacent) columns (of course, the FREQUENCY output needs to be adjacent to the bin data).

Comment: Please add the exact formula you used to answer the question.